# Open and print the contents of a file?

Tags: python, windows, file, directory, path

I am trying to write a program that will open a file and print its contents. I am having some trouble with defining it I suppose? If it is not telling me that "path" is not defined, then it is telling me that "new_dir" is not defined.

Here is the code:

```
import pathlib

def prog_info():
    print("This program will open a file, read and print its contents.")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------")


prog_info()

file_path = new_dir / "numbers.txt"
file_path.parent.mkdir()
file_path.touch()

with path.open("numbers.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip())
```

The file is going to have three numbers that will be printed:

```
22
14
-99
```

Comment: `new_dir` variable is not defined at the moment. You will need to set it to your folder path (eg. `new_dir="C:\Program Files\Folder"`)

Comment: Please include the error stack trace in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("filename or location", 'r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        print(line)
```

I hope this helped you.
You don't need mode, and you don't need the import. All you need is the code provided